# [AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404]

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-sheets, axios

```
const handleSubmit =() => {
   const data ={
      Email:email,
      Phone:phone,
      FirstName:firstName,
      LastName:lastName,
      Message:message,
      City:city
   }
   return (
   axios.post('https://sheet.best/api/sheets/8fab09ad-f573-4efb-b657-da532ca25f4b',data)
   .then((response) => {
    console.log(response)
    setCity('')
    setEmail('')
    setLastName('')
    setMessge('')
    setPhone('')
    setfirstName('')
   })
   .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
  })
   )
}
```

Comment: Please format your question and tell us the problem and what you have already tried: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score -1):

IMHO 404 means that the endpoint that you are looking for does not exist. In some cases, it also means that the method that you are trying to do is wrong like this endpoint exists but it is not of POST type. Try running this API on post man to ensure that you are not doing anything wrong.

Comment: in this case, the endpoint existed, but Vuejs not allow request